# spark streaming:trainging ALS

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, recommendation-engine

I'm new to spark streaming. When I trained spark Streaming on ALS:it was worng.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No ratings available from MapPartitionsRDD[4] at randomSplit at streaming.scala:15\

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.ALS\

import org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating\
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf\
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext\
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}\
import org.apache.spark.streaming._\
object streaming {\
  def main(args: Array[String]) {\
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ALS").setMaster("local[2]")\
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))\
    val ratingStream = ssc.textFileStream(directory="/home/chiao/Downloads/streaming/").map(_.split(',') match {case Array(user,item,rate)=>Rating(user.toInt,item.toInt,rate.toInt)})\
    val rank = 100\
    val numIterations = 12\
    val lambda = 0.01\
     ratingStream.foreachRDD(ratingRDD => {val testTrain =  ratingRDD.randomSplit(Array(0.3, 0.7))\
                                           val model = ALS.train(testTrain(1),     rank,numIterations, lambda)\
                                           val test = testTrain(0).map {case Rating(subject, activity, freq) =>(subject, activity)}\
                                           val prediction = model.predict(test)

    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

my data is:
1,10,100
1,12,100
1,13,100
2,10,100
2,11,100
2,13,100
3,10,100
3,12,100
save as user.txt in file:/home/chiao/Downloads/streaming

Comment: You should add that to the question, qith proper formatting, since this is not a answer